# "Different" Parallax Scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working in my new portfolio, and I want to do a effect like this, in the site:

http://nizoapp.com/

The effect of the iPhone and parts appearing from the sides when we scroll. It's a kind of parallax scrolling.

I tried to search how to do but I can't find. So I "stole" the code saving the page and adapting the code but seems to have many unnecessary things.

Someone know how can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "unnecessary things"?  And why have you tagged this question with "php"?

Comment: If you "borrow" code, at least learn how it works :)

Comment: exactly! what on the earth do you want php to do with client?

Comment: Parth, thank you, but as I said before, I have a bad level of programming and I'm unable to know what I need to do after your math. May you help me a little more giving me a more specific way? Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

Parallax: the apparent displacement of an observed object due to a change in the position of the observer.

Parallax is one particular scroll effect, simulating depth with relative scrolling, [for example](http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/).

If you're interested in scroll effects more generally, then a simple search yields many plugins and [round-ups](http://smashinghub.com/7-jquery-parallax-and-scrolling-effect-plugins.htm).

Comment: Ok, you are saying about maths and scroll events but you are talking with a layman, I know a little of PHP and less than PHP of Javascript. I'm good only with HTML and CSS and it's not enough good to solve my problems :(

Comment: All I said was that you are not looking for "parallax" which is one particular effect. It sounds like you are just interested in neat scroll effects in general, for that you should google or use one of the links to find a plugin.

Answer (score 3):

[image: The idea that i came up with.]

The image here shows how the idea works, **according to me**. The basic idea is that all the elements that move have some distance from a central/non-motile element. As you scroll more, their distance from the this central element reduces - inverse proportion. In the image here, elements are marked with circles and a name given to them (only one moving element given for simplicity, others too can be added). The details follow.

The central element here is called 'A' and the moving one - 'C'. The variables used here:

D => distance of moving element from A
k => any constant > 1 (experiment for good results)
y => distance scrolled (document.body.scrollTop)
dy => vertical distance between A, C
dx => horizontal dist bet. A and C
theta => (predermined) angle between A, C

There's an angle between C and A which depends upon you - set it to any number (radians is the preferable unit). Now, as y increases, D decreases. So, D is given by the relation/formula shown in the figure. Every time you scroll down/up, D is recalculated. From that, dy, dx are calculated and are set as the top, left properties of css for C (which is absolutely positioned). In case you're wondering how to find dy, dx, here's how to do that.

dy = Math.sin(theta) * D
dx = Math.cos(theta) * D

I hope I've given the idea. I could've given the full code, but I wanted you to do something...If you want further help, ask that in comments...:)

Comment: btw...remember, this is, again, just my idea as to how this can be achieved. I haven't read the code of the site you gave...so please don't ask for the exact implementation. :)

Answer (score 0):

basically it uses `scroll` event, and then on certain points it animates the boxes.

Comment: Because the code I used have things relative to the page I took the code. I said stole not because really I stole, but I took the part of code I wanted to use and its use jQuery and some other things, like modernizr. I removed the code which is responsible to do another things, like fade effects, the subscribe area...